ASP.NET 4.8, Exception message: WebSockets is unsupported in the current application configuration
I am getting an error about not being able to run websockets
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: WebSockets is unsupported in the current application configuration. To enable this, set the following configuration switch in Web.config:
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>

Wierd thing is the machines on the face of it do not have 4.0 (nor 4.5) and are running 4.8, without hardcoding to a specific version (which is what they seem to be suggesting in the error) how do I make IIS realise it has a new enough version to do what it needs to do?
I have looked in the registry and can see the version shows correctly there so am a bit stumped and my Google-foo has let me down on this :-)



In your current copy of web.config file, what does the httpRuntime tag looks that? You might edit the question to include that.

ASP.NET 4.x runtime has many compatibility modes to ensure legacy apps are running properly. However, that can be a problem if a developer messed up the settings.
I could reproduce this issue by creating a .NET Framework 4.6 ASP.NET WebForms project and add some WebSocket server side code, as long as I forced the web app to run in .NET Framework 4.0 compatible mode via <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" /> in web.config.
The issue can be resolved if I set <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" /> (as hinted by the exception message) or <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" /> (to match the actual project target framework version).
If you are certain your web app is only going to run on .NET Framework 4.8 and above, you should upgrade the project file to target .NET Framework 4.8, and set <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />, as well as <compilation targetFramework="4.8" /> to remove the compatibility bits.

The Application Pool assigned to your application shows NET version in Application Pools folder in IIS Management Console:
IIS Management Console: Server - Application Pools
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/rUhJP1tk.png

You can try to clear the cache and restart IIS, this will clear the temporary ASP.NET files and restart IIS.
iisreset /stop
del /f /q %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\* 
iisreset /start

